# HTML Button floating right after tab click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am able to get my buttons aligned with my textarea (align to the bottom right) which looks good before I click the tab. Once I click a tab the buttons shift all the way to the right. I suspect it has to do with my display option on tab click. On tab click I am displaying the `div inline` like this:

```
document.getElementById(sectionName).style.display = "inline";
```

When I refresh the page again the default display option seems to works fine.

I have tried to use different display options (e,g. `block`) but they still shift to the right when I click the tabs.

How can I prevent the buttons from shifting on tab click?

index.html:

```
<div id="verify" class="tabcontent statusAreaDiv">
  <span class="statusTextAreaLabel">Status:</span>
    <textarea class="statusTextArea" readonly></textarea>
      <span class="buttonForTextArea">
        <button class="button" id="btn1">Verify</button>
        <button class="button" id="btn2">Download</button>
      </span>
</div>
...
...
<script>
function showTab(event, sectionName) {
    var tabContents = document.getElementsByClassName('tabcontent');
    for (var i = 0; i < tabContents.length; i++) { 
        tabContents[i].style.display = 'none';
        console.log("The table contents is: " + tabContents[i]);
    }
    var tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        console.log("tablinks class is: " + tablinks[i]);
    }

    document.getElementById(sectionName).style.display = "inline";
    event.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

css:

```
.statusAreaDiv {
    min-width: 490px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.statusTextArea{
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    border: 2px solid #dddddd;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-color: light grey;
}

.statusAreaDiv span.statusTextAreaLabel{
    padding-top: 2em;
    font-family: verdana;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    font-size:13px;
}

.statusAreaDiv span.buttonForTextArea{
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}

.button {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #368DEE;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #999;
}
```

Comment: add a div wrapper placeholder around where it will load

Comment: It works fine for me

Comment: @Arex It works fine after you click the tab? It works fine on first page refresh for me, but after i click the tab and it calls `document.getElementById(sectionName).style.display = "inline"` to show the `div` , then the buttons floats all the way to the right of the screen.

Comment: @No-Spex I have a div wrapper placeholder `<div id="verify" class="tabcontent statusAreaDiv"> ... </div>` Do I need another one on top of this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, are looking for this?

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:sans-serif;margin:0;padding:0;}
textarea,button{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:20px 0;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
textarea{
  left:calc(50% - 150px);
  width:300px;
}
button{
  left:calc(50% - 135px);
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea><button>button</button>
```

Comment: This issue is when i click on a tab, the button floats all the way to the right. My current setup is working on page refresh. I need the buttons to stay after i click the tab and when it calls `document.getElementById(sectionName).style.display = "inline"`.  I added my css on there.